# Prevent ProGuard from changing Kotlin suspend functions signature

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard

I'm trying to create a facade for the Android library. Basically, the facade is a Kotlin interface with a list of suspended methods:

```
interface Facade {
    suspend fun doSomeWork(): String
}
```

As it is a facade, I want to keep it from obfuscation, so here is my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keep interface com.some.library.Facade { *; }
```

**The problem**

Then I try to connect this library to my application project. And here the problem raises - I cannot use `Facade#doSomeWork` as a suspend function because its signature was changed. I tried to decompile a library artifact and check the compiled class:

```
public interface Facade {
    @Nullable
    Object doSomeWork(@NotNull Continuation<? super String> var1);
}
```

But, if I disable ProGuard - the signature of the compiled function remains the same as in the source code and I can use it in the application project.

**Attempts to fix the problem**

1. Adding different keep attributes for ProGuard: `-keepattributes Signature,LineNumberTable,RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault,Code`.
2. Adding whole package to the keep attribute: `-keep com.some.library.** { *; }`.
3. Adding Kotlin to the keep attribute:

```
-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlinx.** { *; }
```

4. Replacing `proguard-android-optimize.txt` with `proguard-android.txt`.
5. Disabling ProGuards's full mode: `android.enableR8.fullMode=false`.
6. Creating a separate Gradle module with a facade. This module won't use ProGuard so the method signatures won't be changed. Actually, this is the only working solution I found so far.

**Additional info**

- Android Gradle Plugin - v7.2.2
- Gradle - v7.4
- Kotlin - v1.8.21

**Question**

How can I make ProGuard keep a Kotlin suspend method and prevent signature changes?

Comment: `suspend` isn't a concept in compiled code, that's just syntax the Kotlin compiler knows how to handle transform into normal methods that take a `Continuation`. Are you expecting to see `suspend` in compiled code?

Comment: you are totally correct in saying that `suspend` is just a concept but not a part of bytecode. But, I'm wondering why it's possible to access a suspend function in the debug version of the library? I had assumptions that ProGuard erases some meta information and makes it impossible for the compiler to understand if it is Kotlin code, but I'm not sure about it.